# Bash function is waiting for its subprocess to finish

Tags: bash

What is the best way to get the output of a bash function without waiting for its subprocesses to end? For exemple, the following does not work because bash is not returning until after the `sleep 10&` subprocess has ended.

```
test-fn() {
    sleep 10&
    echo $!
}

pid=$(test-fn)
echo "waiting"
wait $pid
```

Moving the echo inside the test-fn function is not an option : in my real-life case, the subprocess never ends, so the function never returns.

Comment: You might be interested in using start-stop-daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the process substitution is waiting for all write ends of the pipe associated with the stdout of the function call to be closed, but sleep has one end open.  So close it:

```
test_fn() {
    sleep 10 >&- &  # close stdout for sleep, or redirect if desired
    echo $!
}

pid=$(test_fn)
echo "waiting"
wait
```

Note that the top level shell cannot wait on $pid, because pid is not a child of that shell.